# Text scraping, apostrophe, â\x80\x99, regular expression, python

Tags: python, unicode, screen-scraping, python-re

```
<div id="product_description" class="sub-header">
        <h2>Product Description</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Dans une France assez proche de la nôtre, un homme s’engage dans la carrière universitaire. Peu motivé par l’enseignement, il s’attend à une vie ennuyeuse mais calme, protégée des grands drames historiques. Cependant les forces en jeu dans le pays ont fissuré le système politique jusqu’à provoquer son effondrement. Cette implosion sans soubresauts, sans vraie révolution, s Dans une France assez proche de la nôtre, un homme s’engage dans la carrière universitaire. Peu motivé par l’enseignement, il s’attend à une vie ennuyeuse mais calme, protégée des grands drames historiques. Cependant les forces en jeu dans le pays ont fissuré le système politique jusqu’à provoquer son effondrement. Cette implosion sans soubresauts, sans vraie révolution, se développe comme un mauvais rêve.Le talent de l’auteur, sa force visionnaire nous entraînent sur un terrain ambigu et glissant ; son regard sur notre civilisation vieillissante fait coexister dans ce roman les intuitions poétiques, les effets comiques, une mélancolie fataliste.Ce livre est une saisissante fable politique et morale. ...more</p>
    



<div class="sub-header">
```

I want to scrape the text chunk. Could you please tell me what is happening there? My attempt is here.

```
url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/soumission_998/index.html'
response = requests.get(url)
text = response.text

pattern = re.compile(r'<h2>Product Description</h2>\s*</div>\s*<p>(.+?)</p>', re.M | re.S)
brief_dscrp = pattern.findall(text)
brief_dscrp
```

Result is:

['Dans une France assez proche de la nÃ´tre, un homme sâ\x80\x99engage dans la carriÃ¨re universitaire. Peu motivÃ© par lâ\x80\x99enseignement, il sâ\x80\x99attend Ã\xa0 une vie ennuyeuse mais calme, protÃ©gÃ©e des grands drames historiques. Cependant les forces en jeu dans le pays ont fissurÃ© le systÃ¨me politique jusquâ\x80\x99Ã\xa0 provoquer son effondrement. Cette implosion sans soubresauts, sans vraie rÃ©volution, s Dans une France assez proche de la nÃ´tre, un homme sâ\x80\x99engage dans la carriÃ¨re universitaire. Peu motivÃ© par lâ\x80\x99enseignement, il sâ\x80\x99attend Ã\xa0 une vie ennuyeuse mais calme, protÃ©gÃ©e des grands drames historiques. Cependant les forces en jeu dans le pays ont fissurÃ© le systÃ¨me politique jusquâ\x80\x99Ã\xa0 provoquer son effondrement. Cette implosion sans soubresauts, sans vraie rÃ©volution, se dÃ©veloppe comme un mauvais rÃªve.Le talent de lâ\x80\x99auteur, sa force visionnaire nous entraÃ®nent sur un terrain ambigu et glissant ; son regard sur notre civilisation vieillissante fait coexister dans ce roman les intuitions poÃ©tiques, les effets comiques, une mÃ©lancolie fataliste.Ce livre est une saisissante fable politique et morale. ...more']

Comment: The `Ã©`s are evident of UTF-8/ISO-8859-* encoding/decoding confusion _mojibake_ – you will need to share how you get that `text` in the first place, because that's the phase where things are going wrong.

Comment: See now. I have updated the code. @AKX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a scraping library such as BeautifulSoup instead of regexps. It will deal with this sort of Unicode nonsense in a more graceful way.

Either way, what you're seeing here is that when you do `response.text`, `requests` will attempt to guess the encoding of the page based on the response headers. For some reason, `requests` has decided the response is `ISO-8859-1` for no good reason. (If no encoding had been explicitly specified, it would use the `chardet` library.)

You can either force Requests to use `chardet`:

```
response.encoding = None
text = response.text
```

or force the known correct encoding,

```
response.encoding = "utf-8"
text = response.text
```

or just do the decoding from binary content yourself:

```
text = response.content.decode("utf-8")
```

Et voilà:

> ['Dans une France assez proche de la nôtre, un homme s’engage dans la carrière universitaire. Peu motivé par l’enseignement, ...

Comment: There is still a nontrivial amount of web pages which declare an incorrect encoding, or for which `chardet` reports the wrong encoding, and then you are back to "How do I figure out the correct encoding?" For a single page, you can just guess or brute force, but if you are scraping hundreds or thousands (let alone millions) of pages, that's out of the question. There are libraries like [ftfy](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/) which attempt to automate this.

Comment: Yep, good comment. BS4 also does some of that automation, hence the initial sentence here. :) https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings